# Is there a way to access a Page's attribute in PageState class without using widget

Tags: flutter

I want to use `widget.customerInfo.firstName` as an initial text for a `TextFormField`, however I cannot use controller: `TextEditingController(text: widget.customerInfo.firstName)` because there are many `TextFormField` in this class and I need to be able to call each `TextEditingController` by name.

So another option would be to initialize final `firstnameController = TextEditingController();` outside of the Widget build, but the problem is that I wont be able to access `widget.customerInfo.firstName`, so how else could I access `customerInfo.firstName.?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './customerInfo.dart';
import './loginPage.dart';

class UserInfoPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  UserInfoPage2({Key key, this.title, this.customerInfo, this.token})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final CustomerInfo customerInfo;
  final String token;

  @override
  _UserInfoPageState createState() => _UserInfoPageState();
}

class _UserInfoPageState extends State<UserInfoPage2> {  

  void navLogin() {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
  }

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final firstnameController = TextEditingController();
  final _lastnameController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _phoneNumController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                // initialValue: widget.customerInfo.firstName,
                readOnly: false,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'First Name *',
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your first name';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                controller: TextEditingController(text: widget.customerInfo.firstName),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                // initialValue: widget.customerInfo.lastName,
                readOnly: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Last Name *',
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your last name';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                controller: _lastnameController,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                // initialValue: widget.customerInfo.email,
                readOnly: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Email *',
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your email';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                controller: _emailController,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                // initialValue: widget.customerInfo.phoneNum,
                readOnly: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Phone Number *',
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your phone number';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                controller: _phoneNumController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in the `initState` function,

`TextEditingController firstnameController ;`

```
initState(){   
         firstNameController = 
   TextEditingController(text:widget.customerInfo.firstName);
  }
```

this function is called before the build function so you can initialize any variable or do some work like calling function before the widgets are being built